# Creating a Calculated Row Based on Multiple Conditions in a Dataframe with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to find the best way to generate an 'Other' row in my pandas dataframe. 'Other' is calculated by adding up all the Source values that are not 'Total' and then subtracting by the 'Total' values.

Ex: 'Other' =  Total - (Souce_1 + Souce_2 + Souce_3)

Here's an example of what I am starting with:

| Name | Source | Lead | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prop_A | Source_1 | 100 | 3 |
| Prop_A | Source_2 | 50 | 5 |
| Prop_A | Source_3 | 20 | 0 |
| Prop_A | Total | 300 | 11 |
| Prop_B | Source_1 | 200 | 10 |
| Prop_B | Source_2 | 300 | 6 |
| Prop_B | Source_3 | 20 | 0 |
| Prop_B | Total | 700 | 23 |

And this is what I am try to create:

| Name | Source | Lead | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prop_A | Source_1 | 100 | 3 |
| Prop_A | Source_2 | 50 | 5 |
| Prop_A | Source_3 | 20 | 0 |
| Prop_A | Other | 130 | 3 |
| Prop_A | Total | 300 | 11 |
| Prop_B | Source_1 | 200 | 10 |
| Prop_B | Source_2 | 300 | 6 |
| Prop_B | Source_3 | 20 | 0 |
| Prop_B | Other | 180 | 7 |
| Prop_B | Total | 700 | 23 |

I was able to calculate the 'Other' row by using following code, but know this isn't the best way to do it. Wondering if anyone knows a better way?

```
Total_df = df[df['Source'] == 'Total']
All_Sources_df = df[df['Source'] != 'Total']

All_Sources_df = All_Sources_df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).sum()

result = pd.merge(Total_df, All_Sources_df, on=['Name'])

result['Lead'] =  result['Lead_x'] - result['Lead_y']
result['Sale'] =  result['Sale_x'] - result['Sale_y']

result = result[['Name', 'Lead', 'Sale']]

result['Source'] = 'Other'

result = result[['Name','Source','Lead','Sale']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With custom `apply` function and [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (to arrange records for each group):

```
def f(x):
    m = x['Source'].eq('Total')  # mask denoting Total record
    t = x.loc[m, ['Lead', 'Sale']]  # 'Total' values
    return pd.concat([x[~m], t.sub(x.loc[~m, ['Lead', 'Sale']].sum())
                     .assign(Source='Other', Name=x.Name), x[m]])

df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
     Name    Source  Lead  Sale
0  Prop_A  Source_1   100     3
1  Prop_A  Source_2    50     5
2  Prop_A  Source_3    20     0
3  Prop_A     Other   130     3
4  Prop_A     Total   300    11
5  Prop_B  Source_1   200    10
6  Prop_B  Source_2   300     6
7  Prop_B  Source_3    20     0
8  Prop_B     Other   180     7
9  Prop_B     Total   700    23
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. I assumed you may have more columns other than Total, so in this case we can use `~` with `pd.DataFrame.isin` to refer to all the other columns other that Total :

```
(df.set_index('Name')
 .pivot(columns='Source')
 .stack(level=0)
 .assign(other = lambda d: d['Total'] - (d.loc[:, ~ d.columns.isin(['Total'])].sum(axis=1)))
 .stack()
 .reset_index()
 .pivot(index=['Name', 'Source'], columns='level_1')[0])


level_1          Lead  Sale
Name   Source              
Prop_A Source_1   100     3
       Source_2    50     5
       Source_3    20     0
       Total      300    11
       other      130     3
Prop_B Source_1   200    10
       Source_2   300     6
       Source_3    20     0
       Total      700    23
       other      180     7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
cols = ['Name', 'Lead', 'Sale']
m = df['Source'] == 'Total'

other = (df.loc[m, cols].set_index('Name')
           .sub(df.loc[~m, cols].groupby('Name').sum())
           .assign(Source='Other').reset_index())

result = pd.concat([df, other]).sort_values(['Name', 'Source'], ignore_index=True)
print(result)

# Output
     Name    Source  Lead  Sale
0  Prop_A     Other   130     3
1  Prop_A  Source_1   100     3
2  Prop_A  Source_2    50     5
3  Prop_A  Source_3    20     0
4  Prop_A     Total   300    11
5  Prop_B     Other   180     7
6  Prop_B  Source_1   200    10
7  Prop_B  Source_2   300     6
8  Prop_B  Source_3    20     0
9  Prop_B     Total   700    23
```